# Spring MVC, JSP. Include css/js as in Yii framework

Tags: javascript, css, spring, jsp, layout

In Yii I can use packages of css/js files with relations and orderly sequence.

There is something similar in the Spring?

Example

```
'main' => array(
    'baseUrl' => '/templates/',
    'css' => array('css/s/main.css', 'css/s/main-responsive.css'),
    'js' => array('js/s/main.js'),
    'depends' => array('jquery', 'bootstrap'),
),
'bootstrap' => array(
    'baseUrl' => '/templates/',
    'js' => array('js/bootstrap.min.js'),
    'css' => array('css/bootstrap.min.css','css/bootstrap.fix.css'),
    'depends' => array('jquery'),
),
'jquery' => array(
    'baseUrl' => '/templates/',
    'js' => array('js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'),
);
```

Then I use in view template

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerPackage('main');
```

And get in layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.fix.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/s/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/s/main-responsive.css" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/s/main.js"></script>
```